# how to change value of parameter recursive under folder

Tags: linux, bash, sed, rhel, find

under `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` , 
we have network configuration files as

```
ifcfg-conf1
ifcfg-conf2

.
.
.
```

is it possible to change all parameters - `PEERDNS` to `no` , if value is `yes`

expected results on all ifcfg-xxxx files

```
PEERDNS=no
```

wrong  `ifcfg-xxxx` files configuration

```
PEERDNS=yes
```

the reason for this change is because `/etc/resolve.conf` changed after `reboot`
so we need to change all `PEERDNS` variables to `no`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your shell can’t provide this by globbing,

```
find /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts -type f -exec sed -i s/PEERDNS=yes/PEERDNS=no/ {} +
```

This will find all files under `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` and change `PEERDNS=yes` to `PEERDNS=no`.