# find + change recursive value on all metainfo.xml files

Tags: linux, shell-script, sed, grep, find

as we can see from the following grep recursive search

```
 grep -r "<timeout>300</timeout>" /var/lib/ambari-server/resources/common-services/


/var/lib/ambari-server/resources/common-services/ACCUMULO/1.6.1.2.2.0/metainfo.xml:        <timeout>300</timeout>
/var/lib/ambari-server/resources/common-services/AMBARI_INFRA/0.1.0/metainfo.xml:        <timeout>300</timeout>
/var/lib/ambari-server/resources/common-services/ATLAS/0.1.0.2.3/metainfo.xml:        <timeout>300</timeout>
/var/lib/ambari-server/resources/common-services/DRUID/0.10.1/metainfo.xml:        <timeout>300</timeout>
/var/lib/ambari-server/resources/common-services/FALCON/0.5.0.2.1/metainfo.xml:        <timeout>300</timeout>
/var/lib/ambari-server/resources/common-services/FLUME/1.4.0.2.0/metainfo.xml:        <timeout>300</timeout>
/var/lib/ambari-server/resources/common-services/HAWQ/2.0.0/metainfo.xml:        <timeout>300</timeout>
/var/lib/ambari-server/resources/common-services/HBASE/0.96.0.2.0/metainfo.xml:        <timeout>300</timeout>
```

the files `metainfo.xml` under `/var/lib/ambari-server/resources/common-services/`

have the following content

```
<timeout>300</timeout>
```

we want to change by `find` command the value 300 to 400

so expected results will be as the following on all `metainfo.xml` files

```
 <timeout>400</timeout>
```

can this be achieve by find command?

example from `metainfo.xml` file

```
  <commandScript>
    <script>scripts/service_check.py</script>
    <scriptType>PYTHON</scriptType>
    <timeout>300</timeout>
  </commandScript>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem too different from what you did in [a previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/567884/how-to-change-value-of-parameter-recursive-under-folder) a few months ago.

Comment: do you suggested to do like this -  find /var/lib/ambari-server/resources/common-services -type f -exec sed -i s/<timeout>300</timeout>/<timeout>400</timeout>/ {} +

Comment: No, because the `s` command in `sed` uses `/` as the default delimiter, so you need to use another delimiter for that command, maybe `,`: `s,<timeout>300</timeout>,<timeout>400</timeout>,`.  You also need to single quote the whole `sed` expression.

Comment: unfortunately I get -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `300'

Comment: this is work for me -  -type f -exec sed -i s'/<timeout>300<\/timeout>/<timeout>400<\/timeout>/g' {} +

Comment: Do you have `xmlstarlet` (or `xml`) installed? (Test typing: xml <tab> in your shell) It is exactly for editing xml. Think of a typical xml, a bit more complex, <timeout name="some_name">300</timeout> or the node expanding in different lines. All these things are handled by an xml parser.